# How can i append two dictionary on other coulmn without using pandas

Tags: python, csv

I want to make csv file in python that shows 4 column.
each column header is value and key of two dictionary. belowe code append data of second dictionary after the last row of first dictionary. cant find a way to append data of second dictionary to next two column...

```
with open('merged_file.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding = 'UTF-8') as merge_f:
fieldnames = ['negative_word', 'count1', 'non_negative_word', 'count2']
writer = csv.DictWriter(merge_f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

writer.writeheader()
for key in precise_count:
    writer.writerow({'negative_word': key, 'count1': precise_count[key]})
for key in temp_dict:
    writer.writerow({'non_negative_word' : key, 'count2' : temp_dict})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you want to write `precise_count` and `temp_dict` side-by-side.  So, I'm assuming that the keys for both are ordered, so that the first key of precise *corresponds* to the first key of temp, and so on for the other pairs of keys.

The first thing to do, and make sure you like is to put the two dicts together.  You can use `zip_longest()` from the itertools module:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

precise_count = {'apple': -1, 'car': -3, 'taco': -2}
temp_dict = {'shirt': 8, 'happy': 2, 'yummy': 10}

rows = list(
    zip_longest(
        precise_count.items(),
        temp_dict.items()
    ))
```

When I print `rows`, I see something like:

```py
[(('apple', -1), ('shirt',  8)),
 (('car',   -3), ('happy',  2)),
 (('taco',  -2), ('yummy', 10))]
```

If that looks correct, you can move on to writing that list of tuples out to a CSV.  This looks a little different than yours: I'm using `row_dict` to both tell the CSV what the headers should be, and to hold the values for passing to `writerow()`:

```py
import csv

row_dict = {'negative_word': None, 'count1': None, 'non_negative_word': None, 'count2': None}

with open('merged_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as merge_f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(merge_f, fieldnames=row_dict)
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in rows:
        precise, temp = row

        row_dict['negative_word']     = precise[0]
        row_dict['count1']            = precise[1]
        row_dict['non_negative_word'] = temp[0]
        row_dict['count2']            = temp[1]

        writer.writerow(row_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! I just want to knok that if the number of two dictionarys are different does it still work?